# Ubuntu 20.04 / snap

Tags: 20.04, snap

I tried to uninstall darktable 3.2.1snap1 with "Ubuntu Software" without success.
On the cmd line I get the following:

`sudo snap remove darktable`

```
Fehler: snap "darktable" has "remove-snap" change in progress
```

`snap version`

```
snap    2.47.1+20.04
snapd   2.47.1+20.04
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-54-generic
```

`SNAPD_DEBUG=1 SNAP_CONFINE_DEBUG=1 snap run htop`

```
2020/11/28 13:23:41.712561 tool_linux.go:93: DEBUG: snap (at "/snap/snapd/current") is older ("2.47.1") than distribution package ("2.47.1+20.04")
Fehler: cannot find current revision for snap htop: readlink /snap/htop/current: no such file or directory
```

Hmm, no current version installed???
Any hint for me?

Comment: An other snap process is running?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. An other process was running for several minutes in the background.

After reinstall of darktable everything works fine again!

Thx