# How to uninstall a program (which claims it isn't installed)?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, darktable

Darktable seems to be installed twice on my machine, once (probably) via the Software Center (which seems slow / unreliable) and once as a Flatpak (cf. https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.darktable.Darktable). The latter installation is also the current version (3.8) whereas the former is of an older version (3.2.1).

I'd like to remove the older version (3.2.1), but it seems a little weird: Although I can launch it (via command line or via a "launcher") it doesn't seem to be installed - and hence it seems it cannot be removed (neither in Synaptic nor in the command line, cf. various attempts below). Anyway, I can't spontaneously make sense of it and Dr Google also hasn't returned anything helpful yet.

Any ideas?

```
apt-cache policy darktable
darktable:
  **Installed: (none)**
  Candidate: 3.0.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.0.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

vs.

```
darktable

(darktable:160379): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:10.605: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
(...)
```

vs.

```
darktable --version
this is darktable 3.2.1
copyright (c) 2009-2020 johannes hanika
darktable-dev@lists.darktable.org

compile options:
  bit depth is 64 bit
  normal build
  SSE2 optimized codepath enabled
  OpenMP support enabled
  OpenCL support enabled
  Lua support enabled, API version 6.0.0
  Colord support disabled
  gPhoto2 support disabled
  GraphicsMagick support enabled
  ImageMagick support disabled
  OpenEXR support enabled
```

vs.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove darktable
[sudo] password for user_name: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'darktable' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libllvm11* libllvm11:i386* shim*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 161 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

---

**Edit**

```
which darktable; snap list | grep -i darktable; flatpak list | grep -i darktable
/snap/bin/darktable
darktable                3.2.1snap1                  63     latest/stable    sergiusens    -
darktable   org.darktable.Darktable 3.8.0   stable  system
```

Comment: Please add output of `which darktable`; `snap list | grep -i darktable`; `flatpak list | grep -i darktable` to the question by editing it.

Comment: So it's a snap - as expected - and you uninstall it with "sudo snap remove ..."

Comment: @N0rbert expanded the question.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295887/ubuntu-20-04-snap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to run

```
sudo snap remove darktable
```

to remove Snap installation of DarkTable.